# There is an error when I use "git push", what can I do?

Tags: git, git-push

As the title, the mistake is:

```
connected to center SZ
fatal: remote error: Permission denied: bad response message: "Auth failed for operation - push_code.".
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: It's looks like you don't have permission to push in that repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when the password entered after push is wrong.  Please try logging into the repository hosting service. If that was successful, then need to update SSL given in the Hosting service